# Read a file using HTML 5 filessystem API from a String path

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

I am creating a simple text editor as Chrome extension. While using the [fileSystem](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage) API. Though I have seen a several tutorials that explain how to read a file using fileEntry object. I am not sure how to do it using a path like `d:\docs\text.txt`

I have the follwoing code to open a file

```
    fileSystem.root.getFile("d:\file\path\txt.txt",{create: false,exclusive: true},function(fileEntry){
//do something with fileEntry       
}, function(){console.log("error in opeing file")});
```

But this code is failing with

`FileError {code: 9, message: "", name: "InvalidModificationError", NOT_FOUND_ERR: 1, SECURITY_ERR: 2…}`

How do I get rid of InvalidModification error. I have tried a couple of different options but I get a nice error with messages like "File not found" etc. But this one has no user friendly message.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get access to any file you want, you can only access files that the user has chosen through chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry. If that doesn't work for some reason, explain exactly  you're trying to accomplish (e.g. are you saving an ini file?) and we might be able to suggest a different solution.

Comment: I am trying to make a simple text editor. Currently I am using `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry` with `openDirectory` option through which I am showing all the files and folders of the selected folder in a list(ul). I was hoping to show the content of a file when user clicks on a file in a the list.

Comment: OK. If the user has chosen a folder with chooseEntry, you now have recursive access to all the files and folders underneath it. To get to them you need to use the HTML directory API (specifically DirectoryEntry), not access the file directly. The spec for this is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/.